# Xcode: Switching file location from "Relative to Project" to "Relative to Group" error: clang: error: no such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to switch the file location from "Relative to Project":

[image]

To Relative to Group:

[image]

But I'm getting this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/<location of the file>/MyFile.m'
clang: error: no input files
```

My question to you guys is how can switch the location structure without this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try to reselect the file after changing the location type. Is the file marked red in the project navigator?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad what you mean?, can you elaborate ?

Comment: 1. Beneath the type selector is a little folder icon on the right side. When you click it, you can reselect the file. Did you do this? 2. The file is part of the project. Therefore it should be listed in the project navigator. If Xcode cannot find a file, it marks it red.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad that works. Thank you

Comment: Great, I made it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reselect the file. Underneath the location type pull-down you have a little folder icon on the right side. This opens a file selection dialog. Reselect the file.

[image]

Comment: this is easier than what I was going to suggest, which is editing the .xcproj file :)

Comment: Yeah, editing the project file is something you should really avoid.